# Compare 2 dates within a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to compare 2 dates (only dates) of 2 DateTime values within a LINQ query doing this :

```
var appointmentsWithPatch = (from ap in context.DBAppointment where dtStart.Date ==  ap.StartDate.Value.Date select ap).ToList();
```

Knowing that dtStart contains 27/03/2015 and I've one record in my DBAppointment table which has that date as StartDate, it should return one element. However, it does not work and I'm getting null.

Any idea about what's happening here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "and I'm getting null"? Have you looked at the generated SQL? (As a side note, there's no benefit in using a query expression here, and it's worth using vertical whitespace to avoid scrolling horizontally...)

Answer (score 2):

Try to truncate time from `dtStart.Date`:

```
 var appointmentsWithPatch = 
          (from ap in context.DBAppointment 
             where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dtStart.Date) == ap.StartDate.Value.Date 
             select ap)
         .ToList();
```

If you are using EF6, then change `EntityFunctions` to `DbFunctions`.

***Additional info:***

[`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.100).aspx) methods are called ***canonical functions***. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries  portable.

You can find all canonical functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) and all Date and Time Canonical Functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx).

*Don't forget* to add a reference to `System.Data.Objects` and to `System.Data.Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Linq to Entities.

```
var appointmentsWithPatch = (from ap in context.DBAppointment where DbFunctions.DiffDays(dtStart, ap.StartDate) == 0 select ap).ToList();
```

Farhad's answer works as well; the point is that Entity Framework needs to convert your Linq `Expression` into the corresponding SQL, and `DbFunctions` provides the tools to enable it to do that.